# How does hash in file name affect google image search ranking?

Tags: seo, cache, google-image-search, cache-control

In terms of cache optimization it is recommended for [static files like images to cache them forever](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/caching/#static-files). In this case if you want to update an image you have to use a different file name so that the client browser downloads the new image instead of showing the cached one.

**Situation 1**

I don't cache image files. So if I update the file `myimage.png` the file name remains the same.

**Situation 2**

I cache image files forever. That's why I use a hash in the file name.

File name before update: `myimage.a1b2c3.png`

File name after update: `myimage.d4e5f6.png`

**Question**

Am I right that file names *without hashes* are way better in terms of SEO?

Comment: Do you expect to update images after a certain time? If so, what could be a tentative timeframe?

Comment: Yes, there might be updated images after an uncertain time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a long-term basis, I don't think there will be any differences in SEO impact (image-SEO) between the above two methods.

But, there could be short-term SEO impacts when changing filenames during updates.

Google is known to remove non-existent resources from the index after some delay (you can call it a grace period). Whenever you update an image, Google could take some time between de-indexing the old one and indexing the new one.

My ***suggestion*** is this:

Maintain filenames (to prevent short term SEO impacts mentioned earlier) with appropriate `cache-control` headers (for better user experience).   You can set the `max-age` to a reasonable time depending upon a tentative update time in the future and can add `must-revalidate` directive. By this, whenever an image changes, the browser would pick the latest from the server. Otherwise, guided by max-age, the browser can use the cached copy.